# Pytest hangs when running with other threads

Tags: python, multithreading, pytest

I am trying to run pytest from within python after running a thread,
here is a simple example of the case:

```
import time
import threading
import pytest


class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._thread_a = threading.Thread(target=self.do_a)
        self._thread_a.start()
        pytest.main()

    def do_a(self):
        print "a"
        time.sleep(2)
        self.do_a()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
```

but pytest keeps hanging. this is what the output looks like:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
metadata: {'Python': '2.7.10', 'Platform': 'Darwin-17.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit', 'Packages': {'py': '1.5.2', 'pytest': '3.3.2', 'pluggy': '0.6.0'}, 'Plugins': {'session2file': '0.1.9', 'celery': '4.0.0','html': '1.16.1', 'metadata': '1.5.1'}}
rootdir: /Users/path/to/root/dir, inifile:
plugins: session2file-0.1.9, metadata-1.5.1, html-1.16.1, celery-4.0.0
```

and it just hangs like this until I force quit it.
is there any way to make this work?

Comment: what are you expecting to see as the output? "a" being printed every 2 sec?

Comment: @Sanju, yes plus the pytest results, as usual, I have three tests that should be collected and executed. (works well without the thread)

Comment: I am not sure what is the idea behind running the tests this way, but you can pass `-s` and `-vv` to `pytest.main()` to see some verbose outputs. `pytest.main(['-s', '-vv'])`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72715787/8567437

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things to mention:

1. you possibly want to stop the thread if you code is done with something.
2. you may also separate your code from the test code.

Lets say:

**file.py**

```
import time
import threading

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._thread_a = threading.Thread(target=self.do_a)
        self._thread_a.daemon = True
        self._thread_a.start()

    def do_a(self):
        print "a"
        time.sleep(2)
        self.do_a()

    def stop(self, timeout):
        self._thread_a.join(timeout)
```

**test_file.py**

```
import pytest

from .file import A

@pytest.fixture()
def a():
    return A()


def test_sth(a):
    a.start()
    print('I can do sth else')
    a.stop(timeout=1)
```